# How to manage the Azure Audit Logs

Tags: azure, azure-management

Could you please guide me with following points

1. Azure Audit Logs doesn't show logs more than 90 Days. How and where to store all the logs. So we can review it later
2. Is there any Application to which can collect Audit Logs for a subscription and show a nice Dashboard. So we can Analyse

Let me know if more information is required ....

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Audit Logs doesn't show logs more than 90 Days. How and where to
>   store all the logs. So we can review it later

Azure stores audit logs data for 90 days only. I believe they constantly purge the old records. You would need to store them manually some place else if you have a need to view audit logs for older than 90 days.

From this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-audit/

> There are two important limitations to keep in mind when working with
>   audit logs:
>
> 1. Audit logs are only retained for 90 days.
> 2. You can only query for a range of 15 days or less.

---

> Is there any Application to which can collect Audit Logs for a
>   subscription and show a nice Dashboard. So we can Analyse

For last 90 days, you can view audit logs data in Azure Portal itself. Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/audit-logs-in-azure-preview-portal/.